# Excel Selection Change Event Triggered Twice C#

Tags: c#, excel, event-handling, marshalling

I try to invoke selectionchange event in excel but it is triggering twice.
I connected to an open Excel file with marshalling, so the code is as follows

First I post the code on the for Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel_Sol_Taraf_Onaylama_V._00
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void btn_Excele_Baglan_Classtan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                ExcelSinifveOlaylar myExcel = new ExcelSinifveOlaylar();

                Excel.Application oXL = (Excel.Application)myExcel.oXL1("Test.xlsx");

                try
                {
                    myExcel.Excel_OlaylariTanimla();
                    MessageBox.Show("Excel Olayları Tanımlandı");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So below is the ExcelSinifveOlaylar Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

namespace Excel_Sol_Taraf_Onaylama_V._00
{


    class ExcelSinifveOlaylar
    {

        //Marshalling ile excel bağlantısı için nesneler
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;

        //Excel event delegate variables:
        Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler EventDel_BeforeBookClose; //
        Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler EventDel_CellsChange;
        Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler EventDel_SelChange;
        int eventtrigger = 0;
        public Excel._Application oXL1(string strDosyaAdi)
        {
            oXL = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

            int intFileNr = 2;
            //This for statement part is only to connect to the test.xls
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                intFileNr = i;
                try
                {
                    oWB = (Excel._Workbook)oXL.Workbooks.get_Item(i);
                    if (strDosyaAdi == oWB.Name)
                    {
                        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
                        MessageBox.Show("Connected to " + strDosyaAdi + "Aktif Sayfa: " + oSheet.Name.ToString());
                    }

                    Excel_OlaylariTanimla();
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    intFileNr = i;
                }
            }
            return oXL;
        }
        public void Excel_OlaylariTanimla()
        {
            try
            {
                EventDel_SelChange = new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(SelChange);
                oSheet.SelectionChange += EventDel_SelChange;
               // EventDel_CellsChange = new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler(CellsChange);
               // oSheet.Change += EventDel_CellsChange;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        private void SelChange(Excel.Range Target)
        {

            //MessageBox.Show("Selection Changed");
            eventtrigger++;
            MessageBox.Show(eventtrigger.ToString());
        }
}
```

The selectionchange event triggered twice when I change the selected cell in excel. so the eventtrigger becomes 2 instead on 1.

I have feeling that maybe the declaration below in both classes causes this problem

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

but I am not sure.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: What is the use of your `for` loop here? Regardless of the `for`, don't you have two `eventDel_cellschange` in `void Excel_OlaylariTanimla()`??

Comment: With the for loop, I will to connect the desired excel workbook. Maybe it is better to provide the code of oher class to. If you would like to see it I will also post the other class (Form1 class) where the methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please just try one `cell change` event? Try the following code directly instead of creating events within `define events`.

```
//Add an event handler for the Change event of both worksheet objects.
   EventDel_CellsChange = new Excel.DocEvents_ChangeEventHandler( CellsChange);

   xlSheet1.Change += EventDel_CellsChange;

private void CellsChange(Excel.Range Target )
{
   //This is called when any cell on a worksheet is changed.
   Debug.WriteLine("Delegate: You Changed Cells " + 
      Target.get_Address( Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 
      Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value ) + 
      " on " + Target.Worksheet.Name);
}
```

[**Reference MSND**:Handle Events for Excel by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823981)

Comment: @macrobook I updated the code. Your code flow is not convincing. Can you try this sample out please. Then add piece by piece your other extra snippets, try catch and so on.

Comment: I'll try and share the rest if I succeed. Since it is the part of a code, maybe it would be better to provide the whole. And also you can try.

Comment: Triggering the event twice does not have negative effect on the code operation, but I am courious about the reason.

Comment: My question was about Cell Selection change so, I will provide the both two classes so maybe you can try also the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: @macrobook event shouldn't trigger more than once when you change a cell only once. So it's a matter to check. Unless you have two events for `cell select` and `cell change`...

Comment: yet I posted the code of both two classes. Maybe you can try both of them. (What I tried is seperating the excel related code in another class) Thank you for support. I have a feel that in both classes I have the same using statement "Using Excel = ....Excel;" therefore the even could have been triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
    private void btn_Excele_Baglan_Classtan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            ExcelSinifveOlaylar myExcel = new ExcelSinifveOlaylar();

            Excel.Application oXL = (Excel.Application)myExcel.oXL1("Test.xlsx");

            try
            {
               //because of this its occuring 2 times as its already registered from class constructor //myExcel.Excel_OlaylariTanimla();
                MessageBox.Show("Excel Olayları Tanımlandı");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```